# Output directory not set

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I am a total newbie to `gulp.js`,
I started this project and I have an `index.jade` file in `source/jade` directory. Now I have to output `jade2html` files in build directory,
so I used this gulp file:

```
// Gulp.js configuration

// include gulp and plugins
var
    gulp = require('gulp');



// file locations
var
    source = 'source/',
    dest = 'build/';


//  Jader
var jade = require('gulp-jade');

gulp.task('jadehtml', function() {
  var YOUR_LOCALS = {};

  gulp.src('source/jade/')
    .pipe(jade({
      locals: YOUR_LOCALS
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'))
});
```

But somehow when I run `gulp command` it outputs a **blank directory** in build directory. the black directory is named **jade.html**
Please tell me how to fix.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this fix your problem? I just cleaned up your gulp file: grouped the requirements, removed the unused path variables, and removed the demo `gulp-jade` options.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    jade = require('gulp-jade');

gulp.task('jadehtml', function() {
  return gulp.src(['source/jade/*.jade'])
    .pipe(jade())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
});
```

This assumes that all your jade files are in source/jade. As @kosbr said, you can use `return gulp.src(['source/jade/**/*.jade'])` if you need to include files that are in subfolders of source/jade.

Run this with `gulp jadehtml`. If you still have problems at least we'll have a clean place to start debugging from.

Comment: yes thanks.. One more thing, how can i omit some jade files from compiling and not the whole folder?

Comment: The keyword to look up is "globbing". Basically you say something like `['source/jade/*.jade', '!source/jade/filetoignore.jade']`. This tutorial explains it http://zellwk.com/blog/gulp-tutorial-2/ and this site is a good learning tool http://www.globtester.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use `source/**/*.jade` instead of `source/jade/` in your gulp file.

Also, you can use gulp-debug to understand what is wrong.

Comment: ok i am able to fix the file. now an .html file is created but in index.html folder.. why?

Comment: No idea.. Could you insert .pipe(debug({title: 'someTitle:'})) after every pipe to understand what happens? You need add gulp-debug to your project https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-debug